# CSS Block Position Question

Tags: css

I'm pretty new to CSS but I'm hoping this is just something obvious I'm missing.
On [www.sonogenics.co.uk](http://www.sonogenics.co.uk), the Twitter block appears to be floated to the right or have 40px left margin. I have explicity set the margins to be 0px and cleared the floats etc but there has been no effect. From the Firefox WebDeveloper addon, it appears to be a problem with the `.tweet ul` but I can't seem to fix it. Can someone explain to me what is going on?
Cheers
Chris

Comment: Which browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: I've tried Firefox 3.6, 4.0 and Chrome 12 and iOS Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually has `left-padding` and not margin. This is the default styling of a `ul` element. To cancel it, you should put `padding:0;` in the `#tweet ul` style declaration.

A couple of suggestions:

- Use Firebug for development, it is far superior to the WebDeveloper add-on. I was able to immediately spot the problem using it
- Use a CSS reset stylesheet, to remove those default style declarations and normalize it across browsers (the defaults are not consistent between browsers). The best known is the [CSS reset by Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/), which I personally use on every site I develop.

Comment: The defaults are, for the most part, reasonably consistent between browsers, but lists are one of the place where they’re not. IE uses margins to indent lists; other browsers use padding.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Firebug is awesome1

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it

```
#tweets ul { padding: 0px; }
```

`ul`s have a left padding by default in most browsers (i.e. WebKit 40px).

Comment: @downvoter: I would like to know, why you downvoted. I like to learn too, if my answer was wrong.

Comment: Maybe it got voted down because tweets is an id, not a class? If you fix it, maybe it'll get up voted again?

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian thx alot. This could be indeed the point and the downvote is justified. That's why I appreciate comments on down vote. It's better to know the fault than wondering :-) You helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

@chris robinson; i checked your `twitter/style.css` your main problem is that you declare css wrongly that why the properties are not working.

**wrong css declaration :**

```
.twitter #tweets {
    background: #111;
    padding: 0 0px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    text-align:left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color:#AAA;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    margin:0px;
}

.twitter ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #222;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color:#AAA;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin:0px;
    -webkit-padding-start:10x;
}

.twitter #tweets a {
    color: #AAA;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.twitter #tweets a:hover {
    color: #AAA;
}
```

if you check your html your twitter class is inside #tweets not outside of it . So, first correct your css .

**Correct css:**

```
#tweets .twitter {
        background: #111;
        padding: 0 0px;
        padding-bottom:20px;
        text-align:left;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color:#AAA;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        margin:0px;
    }

    #tweets ul.twitter li {
        list-style-type: none;
        background: #222;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color:#AAA;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-right:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        margin:0px;
        -webkit-padding-start:10x;
    }

    #tweets .twitter  a {
        color: #AAA;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #tweets .twitter a:hover {
        color: #AAA;
    }
```

Comment: @Chris I think sandeep has done a sufficient job of fixing your selectors. As another tip, though, don't use css rules that begin with the dash "-", those aren't standard rules, and may not be officially accepted into the css standards.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I jumped the gun a bit and posted the comment before he posted the fix. I was just experimenting with the -webkit-padding stuff but I was under the impression that to have rounded borders in Firefox, you required the `-moz-border-radius` rule?

Comment: @Chris -moz-border-radius is replaced with the standard border-radius rule in Firefox 4+, see http://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/border-radius.  Why would you want to develop for only Firefox anyways?  Anyways, you can see an example jsfiddle I did at http://jsfiddle.net/V4YCn/ using border-radius.  It works in IE 9, Chrome, and Opera.  I tested it with the Firefox 5 beta and it works fine, and I'm sure it will work for Firefox 4 too.  I tried it out in Safari, and it didn't work, which is surprising.  Still, that's 4 out of 5 browsers...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was under the impression that browsers that didn't support `-moz-border-radius` would ignore it and take the `border-radius` rule into account if both were defined? If that's the case, I was just doing it for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Chris ah I see, I guess I haven't researched enough about this then, never mind, ignore my previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your styling isn't being applied because of your css selector.  Your selector is

```
.twitter ul, li {}
```

while your html for the elements are

```
<div id="tweets">
    <ul class="twitter">...</ul>
</div>
```

Your css selector says "style all ul and li that are descendents of any element with the 'twitter' class".  Since the ul isn't contained in an ancestor element with the "twitter" class, it isn't being styled with that rule.

If you want the rule to actually apply, you can either just use the selector

```
.twitter {...}
```

or you can re-class the parent div with "twitter",

```
<div id="tweets" class="twitter">
    <ul class="twitter">...</ul>
</div>
```

or you can use this selector instead,

```
#tweets ul, li {...}
```

which more closely matches your original selector.